# Blazorise SelectedTabChanged method called twice hence ends up selecting wrong tab

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0, blazorise

In my blazor server project, i am using blazorise UI library. Using the tab component works just fine in almost all the cases. However controlling the tabs programmatically, in a couple instances the **SelectedTabChanged** method is invoked twice. First with the actual tab invoked via code secondly on its own with default tab.
e-g invoking **OnSelectedTabChanged** with SecondTab results in selection of FirstTab after second invocation.

Following is my markup:

```
<Tabs @ref="@tabs" SelectedTab="@selectedTab" SelectedTabChanged="@OnSelectedTabChanged">
    <Items>
        <Tab Name="FirstTab">First tab</Tab>
        <Tab Name="SecondTab">Second Tab</Tab>
        <Tab Name="ThirdTab">Third tab</Tab>
    </Items>
</Tabs>
<TabsContent @ref="@tabsContent" SelectedPanel="@selectedPanel" SelectedPanelChanged="@OnSelectedPanelChanged">
                <TabPanel Name=FirstTab">
.
.
.
@code
{
    Tabs tabs = default!;
    TabsContent tabsContent = default!;
    void OnSelectedTabChanged(string name)
    {
        selectedTab = name;
        tabsContent.SelectPanel(name);
    }
    void OnSelectedPanelChanged(string name)
    {
        selectedPanel = name;
    }
}
```

There was a similar issue reported on [github](https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/773) but according to them its fixed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code was that i was manually calling **tabsContent.SelectPanel(name)**; which ends up invoking **OnSelectedPanelChanged** and **OnSelectedTabChanged**

Changing the code to following fixed it:

```
<Row>
<Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.IsAuto.OnDesktop">
  <Tabs @ref="@tabs" @bind-SelectedTab="@selectedTab">
      <Items>
          <Tab Name="FirstTab">First tab</Tab>
          <Tab Name="SecondTab">Second Tab</Tab>
          <Tab Name="ThirdTab">Third tab</Tab>
      </Items>
  </Tabs>
</Column>
</Row>
  <TabsContent @bind-SelectedPanel="@selectedTab>
          <TabPanel Name="FirstTab"></TabPanel>
          <TabPanel Name="SecondTab"></TabPanel>
          <TabPanel Name="ThirdTab"></TabPanel>
.
.
.

@code
{
    public string selectedTab { get; set; }
    Tabs tabs = default!;
    TabsContent tabsContent = default!;
}
```

Controlling the tabs in code via **selectedTab** variable was enough. Details in this [github issue](https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/5431) from creator.